# Google Visualization provide a line in the form of points

Tags: google-visualization

I encountered the following problem when working with Google visualization.

I have 4 arrays of certain numbers:

The first array (X) of numbers is used to display the coordinate along the X axis.

The second and third arrays (Y1 and Y2) are the Y-axis coordinates that you want to represent in the form of lines.

The fourth array (Y3) is also the coordinate along the Y axis, which must be represented as points.

I was able to make lines for the second and third arrays, but after many days of searching, I could not display the 4 array as a point chart. At work with ComboChart also to successes could not come. I would be very grateful for the help. Thank you!

Example:

```
    <div id="Graphic"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


<script>
    let X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; //Х;
    let Y1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.1]; //First line;
    let Y2 = [1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2]; // Second line;
    let Y3 = [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3]; // This should be presented in the form of points, not lines


    google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["line"] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'Х');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Y1');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Y2');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Y3');

        for (let i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            data.addRows([
                [X[i], Y1[i], Y2[i], Y3[i]],
            ]);
        }
        var options = {
            height: 500
        };

        var chart = new 
        google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('Graphic'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using a *Material* line chart  --> `packages: ["line"]`

```
google.charts.Line
```

there are many options that are not supported by *Material*
see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

using a *Classic* chart --> `packages: ["corechart"]`

```
google.visualization.LineChart
```

there are a few ways to achieve,
the easiest would be changing the series type...

```
var options = {
    height: 500,
    series: {
      2: {
        type: 'scatter'
      }
    }
};
```

see following working snippet...

```js
let X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; //?;
let Y1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.1]; //First line;
let Y2 = [1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2]; // Second line;
let Y3 = [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3]; // This should be presented in the form of points, not lines


google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', '?');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y3');

    for (let i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        data.addRows([
            [X[i], Y1[i], Y2[i], Y3[i]],
        ]);
    }
    var options = {
        height: 500,
        series: {
          2: {
            type: 'scatter'
          }
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('Graphic'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="Graphic"></div>
```